# Order By inside view in snowflake to create unique ID

Tags: sql, view, sql-order-by, unique, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My code generates unique ID per row (8 milion rows of data). If I put `ORDER BY` inside `CREATE VIEW AS...` will that keep rows order the same?

Expected result would be to have always the same `ID` no matter who and when executes the view.
I read that `ORDER BY` inside view statement doesn't garantee static sorting and using `ORDER BY` outside the view will allow it to work.

Does snowflake dwh work differently? From what I see in the execution plan it seems straight forward: stars from lowest nested query and moves up while performing operations)

Maybye instead of view I should just go with a table?

```
--sample data
create or replace table determin_sort as (

select uuid,position,val1,val2 
from values ('u98rutu', 66788, 1, 3), 
            ('u999etd', 66788, 2,3), 
            ('voko225', 66788, 2,3),
            ('pp29ccd', 229, 20, 30), 
            ('aa55jmw', 229, 2, 3), 
            ('1ojcugi7', 8994, 2, 30), 
            ('2yrhbf',8994,20,3) 

            v(uuid,position,val1,val2)
);


--view
create or replace view v_determin_sort as

SELECT 'L'||row_number() over (order by position) as LID 
        uuid, 
        position,
        val1,
        val2 FROM (SELECT 
                   row_number() over (partition by position order by uuid) as rn, * 
                   FROM determin_sort
                   QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by position order by uuid) = 1
                   ORDER BY UUID);
--query the view
SELECT * FROM v_determin_sort ORDER BY LID;
```

Comment: There is no mention in the documentation regarding `ORDER BY` and views.  Perhaps Snowflake does allow the syntax and do the ordering.  However, I would be very careful because this is not documented behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code generates unique ID per row (8 milion rows of data). If I put ORDER BY inside CREATE VIEW AS... will that keep rows order the same?

The `ORDER BY UUID` that you have in the sub-select of the view is meaningless, as demonstrated by the lines that care about order (the `ROW_NUMBER`'s) having their own `ORDER BY`'s

> Expected result would be to have always the same ID no matter who and when executes the view. I read that ORDER BY inside view statement doesn't garantee static sorting and using ORDER BY outside the view will allow it to work.

ORDER BY is side the view will "order the data" at that point of time, but if you join the table to some other table, with the other table first, the order of the views is meaning less.

```
SELECT t.*, v.*
FROM table_name AS t
JOIN view_name AS v ON t.uuid = v.uuid
```

the data can order those rows in any fashion it likes. And if this query has an order by added to it, like `ORDER BY t.column_a` what value was created by ordering inside the view, it's all presentation.

The more important this is if you want the ID's to be stable, requires the values used in the `ORDER BY`'s used in the `ROW_NUMBERS`'s to be stable (aka no duplicates for you example data in UUID).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_determin_sort AS
SELECT 
    'L' || row_number() OVER (ORDER BY position) AS lid 
    ,uuid
    ,position
    ,val1
    ,val2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY uuid) AS rn /* this row is not needed as the QUALIFY is doing the work */
        ,uuid
        ,position
        ,val1
        ,val2
    FROM determin_sort
    QUALIFY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY position ORDER BY uuid) = 1
    ORDER BY UUID /* this order by does nothing */
);
```

This will give the same results, AS LONG AS the data in the table does not change, if new `positions` or 'UUID' are inserted/deleted you will get different results across those changes. Also UUID appears to be a string, which seems a strange value to sort on, as UUID are often random in there bits set with respect to time, so why is one UUID more valid as the best/lastest/most wanted UUID for any `position`

Comment: Would adding `ORDER BY LID` outside sub-query do any difference?

Comment: Other question - what if replace `determin_sort` table with a view as well? Would `LID` view code still work or would it be non-deterministic if sourcing from another view?

Comment: Assuming that source view would also have unique `uid`

Comment: I feel like you are confusing order of rows, with order of rows in a `row_number` function, The former is meaningless. The later is defined by the data you have (and it's uniqueness) in the ORDER BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER call.. IFF you want the output of the ROW_NUMBER to be "stable".

Comment: And by meaning less, it has meaning but only to things the use the sorted nature of the data, but then if you have a VIEW and you need the data to be sorted, you should sort the results before you consume them in the fashion that has meaning to you. If you do not make meaning of the order of the data (because for example you aggregate it or join it to other data) then having sort in inside the view, might not add value, and might just waste time, that slows you query down.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that you will get the same LID number for the same row each time the view is run **unless your ORDER BY in the window function IS UNIQUE**.

If you were to order by LID within the view, I believe in this specific case you would be fine because you are calculating the LID column first then sorting on it.  Although I would advise against adding a sort operation to a view as sort is an expensive operation.

Comment: Which window function you mean? The one in nested or outer query?

Comment: Your outer query, the one calculating your LID.  If `position` is not unique there, then the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is non-deterministic.  Meaning that, for example, L1 might be assigned to one specific row the first time you query the view, but assigned to a completely different row the next time.

If position is unique within the outer query, then I would be questioning why you need a row_number function generating a unique ID.

Comment: The partitioning by `position` in the sub-query means there is only 1 position value in the outer `ROW_NUMBER`, the real stable requirement is based on `UUID` being unique.

Comment: `'L'||row_number() over (order by position) as LID` is ordered by few more columns but `uuid` makes each record in the end unique.

Comment: Based on your sample data you should be fine.  And Simon's answer makes a great point about the sorting when joining the view to another table.